# Insert into table select from table a and table b where

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert data into a table by joining two tables with a where condition that each id matches.

```
INSERT INTO SALES(T_ID, SF)
SELECT B.T_ID, B.SF
FROM HIS B, SALES C
WHERE C.REP_ID=B.REP_ID;
```

I am getting an error that I cannot insert NULL into ("c.REP_ID")

I am not trying to insert anything into c.rep_id. I want to insert values into t_id, sf from HIS table where the rep_id on his table = rep id on sales table.

Comment: try running the Select seperately and verify if its returning the required result

Comment: In WHERE condition you are having "WHERE C.REP_ID=B.REP_ID;
" and "C" is SALES table, are you sure you want to again insert same data into SALES table once again?

Comment: Just make REP_ID in sales Identity. So afterwords you will not face this kind of error....

Comment: @nadeem_mk yea the required result are there. How do I insert those result into SALES table under columns T_ID and SF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO SALES (T_ID, SF)
SELECT h.T_ID, h.SF FROM HIS h, SALES C
WHERE C.REP_ID=B.REP_ID;
```

Note: Make sure that the data comes from select tables is equally compare and valid with the datatypes of the columns where you inserting.

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means that the column `REP_ID` in the `SALES` table has a NOT NULL constraint. Your INSERT statement doesn't insert any value into that column (you only insert `T_ID` and `SF`) and presumably there are no before-row triggers that will set that column for you.