# Insert data form two tables into another table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm a beginner in database and I've been trying to insert data from one table to another one.
I have following code:

```
$codigoAlumno = $_GET['txtValidarCodigo'];
$codigoMateria = $_GET['txtValidarMateria'];

if($codigoAlumno && $codigoMateria){

include('conexion.php');
//GUARDAR COINCIDENCIA CON CODIGOS

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cat_materia WHERE vchCodigoMateria='$codigoMateria'"); 
$rowStn = mysql_num_rows($query);

$query_2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cat_alumno WHERE iCodigoAlumno='$codigoAlumno'");
$rowSub=mysql_num_rows($query_2);

if($rowSub == 0){

    echo "No coicide con ningun registro";  

}else{

    if($rowStn == 0){

        echo "No coicide con ningun registro";  

    }else{

        //AGREGAR DATOS
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO cat_rel_alumno_materia(iCodigoAlumno,vchCodigoMateria,fCalificacion)VALUES('$codigoAlumno','$codigoMateria'");
        $registro = mysql_affected_rows();


        echo 'Se ha completado el regisitro '.$registro;

    }
}
}else{

    echo "Ingrese los campos";
}
```

Really, I've searched different waysto do, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Your code or whatever you planned to attach as an example or a starting situation hasn't come through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert into table select from table a and table b where](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137183/insert-into-table-select-from-table-a-and-table-b-where)

Comment: OT: Best if you escape/validate your input before throwing it into a SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing two separate queries with PHP and inserting the result row by row into a database is not very efficient and it's a lot of hard work. You can instead make use of the [INSERT SELECT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

> With INSERT ... SELECT, you can quickly insert many rows into a table from one or many tables.

Thus a large part of your code can be replace with:

```
INSERT INTO cat_rel_alumno_materia(iCodigoAlumno,vchCodigoMateria,fCalificacion) 
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM cat_alumno
```

Taking care to replace col1, col2, col3 as appropriate. If you want to combine from both cat_alumno and cat_materia

you can DO

```
INSERT INTO cat_rel_alumno_materia(iCodigoAlumno,vchCodigoMateria,fCalificacion) 
SELECT c1.col1, c2.col2, c2.col3 FROM cat_alumno c1 INNER JOIN cat_materia c2 ON iCodigoAlumno = vchCodigoMateria
```

Note: since you have not mentioned what your tables are like, the above query is only given as a general guideline. it will not work as is, you will have to make slight modifications to suite your table structures.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert data from one table into another you can use an `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table_1(col_1, col_2)
SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM table_2
```